# How to merge the Time Series Panda Data Frame without loosing the row?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, time-series

### Heading

1. How to Merge the Time Series DataFrame without loosing rows?
2. The final result DataFrame shape should based on which DataFrame have larger DataFrame shape.

DF1:

```
0  17.12.2014 13:56:56                        1.9
1  17.12.2014 13:56:58                        3.1
2  17.12.2014 13:56:59                        2.8
3  17.12.2014 13:57:10                        2.3
4  17.12.2014 13:57:11                        3.1
```

df1.shape is around 3000

```
df2:
       Time                                    Value
1   17.12.2014 13:55:56                        2.9
2   17.12.2014 13:55:58                        6.0
3   17.12.2014 13:55:58                        3.6
4   17.12.2014 13:55:59                        2.8
5   17.12.2014 13:56:07                        1.9
6   17.12.2014 13:56:12                        2.9
7   17.12.2014 13:56:12                        3.0
8   17.12.2014 13:56:13                        1.8
9   17.12.2014 13:56:15                        2.2
10  17.12.2014 13:56:15                        2.0
11  17.12.2014 13:56:41                        1.7
12  17.12.2014 13:56:41                        2.4
13  17.12.2014 13:56:42                        2.8
14  17.12.2014 13:56:42                        1.9
15  17.12.2014 13:56:43                        2.8
16  17.12.2014 13:56:43                        1.7
17  17.12.2014 13:56:44                        2.8
18  17.12.2014 13:56:45                        1.7
19  17.12.2014 13:56:59                        2.8
20  17.12.2014 14:03:08                        1.7
```

df2.shape is around 20000

```
df3 

1   17.12.2014 13:56:12                        3.2
```

df3.shape is around 5000

I need the result DataFrame as below and the result dataFrame Size should (20000) as per DF2 size:

```
    Time                   Value1          Value2                       Value3                
1   17.12.2014 13:55:56        NaN             2.9                            NaN                    
2   17.12.2014 13:55:58        NaN             6.0                            NaN                    
3   17.12.2014 13:55:58        NaN             3.6                            NaN                    
4   17.12.2014 13:55:59        NaN             2.8                            NaN                    
5   17.12.2014 13:56:07        NaN             1.9                            NaN                    
6   17.12.2014 13:56:12        NaN             2.9                            NaN                    
7   17.12.2014 13:56:12        NaN             3.0                            3.2                    
8   17.12.2014 13:56:13        NaN             1.8                            NaN                    
9   17.12.2014 13:56:15        NaN             2.2                            NaN                    
10  17.12.2014 13:56:15        NaN             2.0                            NaN                    
11  17.12.2014 13:56:41        NaN             1.7                            NaN                    
12  17.12.2014 13:56:41        NaN             2.4                            NaN                    
13  17.12.2014 13:56:42        NaN             2.8                            NaN                    
14  17.12.2014 13:56:42        NaN             1.9                            NaN                    
15  17.12.2014 13:56:43        NaN             2.8                            NaN                    
16  17.12.2014 13:56:43        NaN             1.7                            NaN                    
17  17.12.2014 13:56:44        NaN             2.8                            NaN                    
18  17.12.2014 13:56:45        NaN             1.7                            NaN       
19  17.12.2014 13:56:56        1.9             NaN                            NaN
20  17.12.2014 13:56:58        3.1             NaN                            NaN
21  17.12.2014 13:56:59        2.8             2.8                            NaN
22  17.12.2014 13:57:10        2.3             NaN                            NaN
23  17.12.2014 13:57:11        3.1             NaN                            NaN
20  17.12.2014 14:03:08        NaN             1.7                            NaN
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an [outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join)

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'outer', on = 'Time')
```

This does full outer join. You can change `outer` to `left`, `right` for left/right outer join.

Comment: pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'outer', on = 'Time').sort_values(by = 'Time')

Comment: working with only two dataFrame. if I add third frame it's shows how got multiple value error. Assume df1 having 1000  df2 having 2000. When I merged I got around 3000 rows. Assume I have another 3000 row in df3. Now I repeated with same command like pd.merge(merged, df3, how = 'outer', on = 'Time').sort_values(by = 'Time') .Now expectation is 6000 rows. But I am getting final merge with 9000 rows

Comment: @thangaraj1980, 1. your time column has duplicated value; 2. When you do outer join, the result shouldn't be near len(df1) + len(df2). That indicates that df1['time'] and df2['time'] almost never match

Answer (score 1):

Set the index to be the time and then join using `outer`. You can use `reduce` from `functools` to make the syntax concise.

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda l,r: l.join(r, how='outer'), [df.set_index('Time') for df in [df1, df2, df3]])
```

#### Output:

```
                     Val1  Val2  Val3
Time                                 
17.12.2014 13:55:56   NaN   2.9   NaN
17.12.2014 13:55:58   NaN   6.0   NaN
17.12.2014 13:55:58   NaN   3.6   NaN
17.12.2014 13:55:59   NaN   2.8   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:07   NaN   1.9   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:12   NaN   2.9   3.2
17.12.2014 13:56:12   NaN   3.0   3.2
17.12.2014 13:56:13   NaN   1.8   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:15   NaN   2.2   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:15   NaN   2.0   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:41   NaN   1.7   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:41   NaN   2.4   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:42   NaN   2.8   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:42   NaN   1.9   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:43   NaN   2.8   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:43   NaN   1.7   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:44   NaN   2.8   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:45   NaN   1.7   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:56   1.9   NaN   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:58   3.1   NaN   NaN
17.12.2014 13:56:59   2.8   2.8   NaN
17.12.2014 13:57:10   2.3   NaN   NaN
17.12.2014 13:57:11   3.1   NaN   NaN
17.12.2014 14:03:08   NaN   1.7   NaN
```

Note, in your provided input you have two entries for `17.12.2014 13:56:12` in `df2` so the value in `df3` was brought to both of those rows.

Comment: I tried it's merging. But i need to check whether the data are merged properly.one more clarification required my actual df1 shape is (3000,2) df2 size is( 20000,2) and df3 is(50000,2). But final merge showing (82,000,3). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @thangaraj1980 so long as each `DataFrame` has a column named `'Time'` and you `.set_index('Time')` the join is guaranteed to match rows based on `Time`. Now in your example the time was always in the same format, so I didn't need to do anything, but if they are in different formats it may be safer to first convert them to a `datetime` with `pd.to_datetime` which formats all dates to be the same

Comment: @thangaraj1980 The length of the final output depends on the duplication within each frame. In your sample data, there are duplicate time entries so this is likely the cause. For instance if you have 2 `DataFrames` each with only 10 entries that all have the same exact time, the result of an outer merge is 100 rows (10*10). Plausibly your result could have anywhere between 50,000 and 3 Trillion rows, so 82,000 rows is unsurprising.

Answer (score 1):

The join method is built exactly for these types of situations. You can join any number of DataFrames together with it. The calling DataFrame joins with the index of the collection of passed DataFrames. To work with multiple DataFrames, you must put the joining columns in the index.

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [df.set_index('Time') for df in dfs]
dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])
```

Learned from @Ted Petrou, while taking his online course.

With merge:

```
df1.merge(df2,on='Time', how='outer').merge(df3,on='Time')
```

OR

```
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Time', how='outer'),df3,on='Time')
```